# Clarity Ferm question

Tags: gluten-free

I've just started brewing at home with Clarity Ferm - in our first attempt we added much more than intended (over half the tube to a 1 gallon brew). Has anyone else done this - do you know if it would have any adverse effects and is still safe to drink?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the tube 10ml ?

Answer (score 1):

Clarity Ferm is a solution, supplied in 10ml tubes, that contains "proline-specific endo-protease derived from a selected strain of Aspergillus niger". It basically chops up proteins (polypeptides) to stop the formation of "chill haze" and and as a useful side effect it chops up gluten proteins to make gluten free beer (interesting!).

This enzyme is not notified as poisonous in elevated quantities and would probably denature anyway in very acidic conditions (think stomach acid).

From the manufacturers spec sheet I see that 10ml is good for 5 gallons. So using 5ml in 1 gallon is not a vast "overdose". I note that the recommended dosage is doubled for beers with >20% wheat in the grain bill. So it can be used in greater and lesser amounts.

IMHO I would bottle and condition the beer to allow the enzyme to work on the gluten. After a few months I would sample it.

Comment: I agree, if the beer tastes good I wouldn't worry too much, but I would send White Labs an email just to make sure.

Comment: Just an alert for parties wishing to brew "gluten free".

Clarity Ferm, to my knowledge, produces "Gluten reduced" beers, less than 10ppm using standard dosages. This is NOT "gluten free", and Clarity Ferm do not make such a claim.